# Time before IP boost?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a way to see how much time is left before the daily IP boost - except on the statistics screen after the match? Or is that the only place? I've looked all around the interface and couldn't find this info anywhere... I know I could keep track of time in my head, but I already know that, and that's not what I want to do - I would like to be able to check it somewhere if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update this question, it is visible on your summoner page on your banner. It will either give you a time until it is available or say that it *is* currently available.

Answer (score 2):

as stated here
http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=140311
it's not possible (yet)